# Custom URL name on document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

Is it possible to have the URL name that leads to a SharePoint Online document library, to be different from the library name itself?

**Example:**

```
Library Name = Business-Records-2018-Staff
The URL = ..../BusRec2018/...
```

Is this possible with SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the Library with the short name you want the URL to be, then in the Library Settings you can change the Title of the Library.

You can't change the Doc Lib URL post-creation.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  That's exactly what I was curious about!